# Homotopy equivalence onto special fiber

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, morse-theory

The following proposition appears in Peters and Steenbrink's book on *Mixed Hodge Structures*.

> **Proposition([Peters--Steenbrink, Proposition C.11])** If $f\colon X\to\Delta$ is proper and smooth over $\Delta^\ast:=\Delta-\{0\}$, then the inclusion $X_0\hookrightarrow X$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Does anyone know a reference for the proof of this result?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think the conditions imply that $f$ is a fibration. It's a basic fact from topology that the pullback is then a homotopy pullback. If an arrow in a homotopy pullback is a homotopy equivalence, then the parallel arrow is also an equivalence.

Comment: I think the importance of properness is that it deals with "missing points": consider taking some fibration over $\Delta$ and then deleting some point in the domain. If you do it wrong, you can end up with something which doesn't contract right: think about something like $I^2\to I$ by coordinate projection. Deleting a point turns the source from contractible and homotopy equivalent to any given fiber to homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Why do you believe that to be the case? Thanks!

Comment: @KReiser I agree intuitively. I mean, I intuitively think it should be like some sort of valuative criterion that takes a point $p$ in some $f^{-1}(t)$ for $t\in\Delta^\ast$ and 'flows it towards $0$' and properness is needed to say that this flow actually reaches $X_0$, but I don't know how to make this precise. My goal, by the way, is to try and finally understand the classical topology analogue of Grothendieck specialization where for $Y\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O})$ proper over a Henselian DVR (although you don't even need DVR) you have that $Y$ and $Y_0$ (the special fiber)

Comment: have the same $\pi_1$. What I am asking here is obviously more intense, as I am asking an extension beyond an infinitesimal neighborhood to an honest to god one, and so I am not surprised that some conditions might be necessary.

Comment: Admittedly I don't have an explicit proof in hand right now but I totally agree with you on how it should work in principle. I'll see if I can find something more substantive to say as an answer.

Comment: A similar question is asked and answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264940/proper-family-deformation-retracts-onto-special-fiber/266601 It was first proved by Clemens in the case $X_0$ is normal crossing divisors.

Comment: It is more wishful thinking than a belief on my part. I am largely ignorant on algebraic geometry, but do a lot of homotopy theory, so my perspective is this: You have a pullback with two spaces being contractible. If the desired homotopy equivalence seems to be a 'basic topological fact', then one proves it either by hand or shows that the pullback is a homotopy pullback (at least this is my experience). A sufficient condition is for $f$ to be a fibration. Note that $\{0\}\to \Delta$ is not a fibration and also $\{0\}\to U$ is not.

Comment: @AGlearner Thanks, but I checked the references and they don't actually seem to claim what is being asked, at least in the generality I'd like (e.g. it seems like the Clemens reference assumes the special fiber is a SNCD)

Comment: (PS, I realized you already said this assumption -- does Persson do it in full generlaity? It also seems the answer is no)

Comment: First, my understanding is that Clemens proved the case for normal crossing divisors (not only SNCDs), namely, the divisor can be non-reduced. The reference is his paper _Degeneration of Kahler Manifold_ in 1970's. Second, my guess is that it will imply all general case. Let's try: for an arbitrary family $X\to \Delta$, take a log resolution $\tilde{X}\to \Delta$ so that $\tilde{X}_0$ is of normal crossing, then there is retraction $\tilde{X}\to \tilde{X}_0$, let's take composition of rational maps $X\dashrightarrow \tilde{X}\to \tilde{X}_0\to X_0$. This extends to a regular map (is it?)

Comment: @AGlearner With regards to SNCD, you may be right -- I don't have access to the article right now, and only gave it a cursory glance. Next, are you claiming the retraction is regular in general? Anyways, I was sort of hoping for an answer that didn't require any kind of resolution -- this seems easier than that. Peters and Steenbrink call this a 'basic fact'. I was hoping for an answer that is similar to the proof of Ehresmann's theorem. It's a bit strange to me that this result is so hard to find, especially given its importance, so maybe Peters--Steenbrink's statement is misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, Clemens proved the case for normal crossing divisors. The general case will follow from this result, which I'll provide proof later.

> Theorem. [(Clemens, 1977)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-44/issue-2/Degeneration-of-K%C3%A4hler-manifolds/10.1215/S0012-7094-77-04410-6.full) If $X$ is a smooth complex manifold and $f:X\to \Delta$ is a proper family. Suppose $f$ is smooth
> over $\Delta^*$, and $X_0=f^{-1}(0)$ is normal crossing divisor, then there is a strong
> deformation retract from the total space $X$ to the central fiber
> $X_0$.

**Remark 1.** Here $X_0$ being a normal crossing divisor means $X_0=\cup_im_iD_i$ and the $D_i$ are smooth proper varieties meeting transversely among each other and $m_i\ge 1$. The local equation of a point $x_0\in X_0$ in a neighborhood of $X$ is analytically equivalent to $t=x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_k^{m_k}$.

Note a normal crossing divisor is different from *simple normal crossing divisor*, in which the central divisor is reduced ($m_i=1$) and the family is called *semi-stable*. To get a semi-stable family from $X\to \Delta$, one need to take a base change with respect to a finite cover $p:\tilde{\Delta}\to \Delta$ where $\deg(p)$ is the l.c.m. of $m_i$. (People studying asymptotic Hodge theory prefer to work with a semi-stable family, that's why various literature, e.g., by David Morrison, on Clemens-Schmid sequence work with a semi-stable family, even though the existence of the limiting mixed Hodge structure [only rely on normal crossing condition](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.03983).)

**Remark 2.** A [strong deformation retract](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongDeformationRetract.html) $F:X\times I\to X$ means $F$ is a deformation retract ($F_0=F(\cdot,0)=Id_X$ and $F_1=F(\cdot,1)$ sends $X\to X_0$) and satisfies $F(x,t)=x$ whenever $x\in X_0$.

Now let's prove the general case based on Clemens' theorem.

> Claim: Let $Y\to \Delta$ be a proper family and smooth over
> $\Delta^*$. Then there is a strong deformation retract of $Y$ onto
> $Y_0$.

**Proof.** By Hironaka, there is a log resolution
$$\sigma: X\to Y,$$
where $\sigma$ is isomorphism over $Y\setminus Y_0^{sing}$ and $X_0=\sigma^{-1}(Y_0)$ is a normal crossing divisor.

We define $G:Y\times I\to Y$ by

$$
G(y,t)=\begin{cases}\sigma F(\sigma^{-1}(y),t),\: y\notin Y_0;\\
y,\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: y\in Y_0.
\end{cases}
$$
I claim that $G$ is a strong deformation retract of $Y$ onto $Y_0$. In fact, it suffices to check the continuity. Since the points know where to flow outside $Y_0$, it suffices to check continuity on $Y_0$. Let's take a sequence of points $(y_n,t_n)$ on $Y\times I$ whose limit point is $(y_0,t_0)$ with $y_0\in Y_0$. Then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}G(y_n,t_n)=\sigma\lim_{n\to\infty}F(\sigma^{-1}(y_n),t_n).$$ Since $X$ is proper, $\sigma^{-1}(y_n)$ converges to a point $x_0\in \sigma^{-1}(y_0)\subseteq X_0$. By strongness of $F$, $F(\sigma^{-1}(y_n),t_n)\to (x_0,t_0)$, so $\lim_{n\to \infty}G(y_n,t_n)=(\sigma(x_0),t_0)=(y_0,t_0)$. Therefore $G$ is continuous on $Y_0\times I$. $\Box$

**Final remark.** One can think of the retraction as describing a flow that sends the vanishing cycles to the singularity on central fiber and send other points to smooth locus $Y_0^{sm}$. In the normal crossing case, the vanishing cycle is the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of $D_1\cap D_2$ (say two components) in $Y$, which is a circle bundle. The retraction is to flow each circle over $y\in D_1\cap D_2$ to the point $y$. To me, this is the topological picture behind the argument.

In addition to the references listed in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/266601), one can refer to Clemens' original paper [Cle77] (especially Theorem 5.7) for the strong deformation retract theorem in normal crossing case. Besides, [Nicolaescu's notes](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/sing.pdf) (e.g. Chapter 14) is also a good introduction to this subject.

[Cle77]: Clemens, C. H.
Degeneration of Kähler manifolds.
Duke Math. J. 44 (1977), no. 2, 215–290.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to type this up! I'll give it a careful read soon. Again, I'd prefer that we didn't have to use resolution, but again maybe that's unavoidable.

Comment: Follow-up question: does this work when the total space $X$ itself is not smooth? Or, in that case, do you need to stratify your spaces delicately as in Goresky--MacPherson?

Comment: @AlexYoucis In general case, the total space does not need to be smooth (log resolution always bring us to the smooth case). Clemens does work in the case of smooth total space. I edited and added the assumption.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I don't know an argument without using resolution of singularities. Let's say central fiber has only an ordinary double point, do you know how to do it?

Comment: I do not, at least rigorously (I can se intuitively why it's true). This is not very surprising as I haven't really made much attempt to understand the proof in Clemens beyond the basic intuition you also indicated above. In any case, it's no matter, as this is all I was really after. Thank you very much!