The existence of a tubular neighborhood around a fiber that can deform retract onto the fiber
"In Campana's paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01902v2), in the first paragraph of the proof of Lemma 1.1, the author claims the existence of a deformation retraction $f^{-1}(U) \rightarrow$ $f^{-1}(0)$ for some Stein open subset $U$ in the base space.
I use the term "tubular neighborhood" of a fiber $f^{-1}(0)$ to denote $f^{-1}(V)$ for some open neighborhood $V$ of $0$.

Question: How can one find (by Lojasiewicz's triangulation theorem) such a Stein $U$ so that the map $f^{-1}(U)
\rightarrow f^{-1}(0)$ is a deformation retraction?
(If this is too difficult, the 'Stein' condition may be omitted.)

Clues:
1, From various references, it seems that the fibration in Lemma
1.1 refers to a surjective holomorphic map with connected fibers (but not a topological fibration).
2, In the published version of this paper, the author used Lojasiewicz's
triangulation theorem to obtain such a $U$.
3, The Lojasiewicz's triangulation theorem can be stated as follows: Let $X$ be complex space and $A$ an analytic subset of $X$. Then there exists a triangulation of $|X|$ in which $A$ appears as the support of a subcomplex. In particular, there exists an open neighborhood $E$ of $A$ such that both $E$ and $\bar{E}$ can be retracted onto $A$.
4, I think in paragraph 1 in page 16 of this paper by  Kollar  (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.02614) also involve the existence of the similar deformation retraction.
5, According to the suggestions of @Alex Youcis, one can  refer to Homotopy equivalence onto special fiber  for a method to directly construct the deformation retraction map. For related discussions, see here: Using morse theory to construct a deformation retraction  and  Using the theory of simplicial complex to construct a deformation retraction.
I suspect that Lojasiewicz's triangulation theorem could be more powerful than directly constructing the deformation retraction map.
Any comments or insights (particularly regarding Campana's use of Lojasiewicz's triangulation theorem) would be greatly appreciated.

Does the answer to this question help you?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400234/homotopy-equivalence-onto-special-fiber

@AlexYoucis  Thank you, I know that post.  In fact, I have posted two posts related to them (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4939526/using-the-theory-of-simplicial-complex-to-construct-a-deformation-retraction)   (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4938418/using-morse-theory-to-construct-a-deformation-retraction)    I think in that post, the Lojasiewicz's triangulation theorem  may not be used.  I guess the Lojasiewicz's triangulation theorem may be more powerful than directly constructing the deformation retraction map

Do you have a reference for the triangulation theorem?

@red_trumpet  The version I write above is found in  page 33 of the book:  Barth, Hulek, Peters, Van de Ven, Compact Complex Surfaces, Second Enlarged Edition.  I cannot understand the original paper of Lojasiewicz 64'.


Let $X$ be complex space and $A$ an analytic subset of $X$. [...] [T]here exists an open neighborhood $E$ of $A$ such that both $E$ and $\bar E$ can be retracted onto $A$.

Note that this can be strengthened: The neighborhood $E$ deformation retracts to $A$, because sub-complexes are neighborhood deformation retracts.
Then this is enough: Clearly the fiber $f^{-1}(0)$ is an analytic subspace of $X$. So by the triangulation theorem, there exists an open neighborhood $E$ of $f^{-1}(0)$ which deformation retracts to $f^{-1}(0)$. Since $f$ is proper, the set $f(X \setminus E)$ is closed. Hence there exists a Stein neighbourhood $U$ of $0$, with $U \subset B \setminus f(X \setminus E)$. Then $f^{-1}(U) \subset E$, and so $f^{-1}(U)$ also deformation retracts to $f^{-1}(0)$.
And by the way, I wouldn't call this a "tubular neighborhood", which is a different thing.

@red-trumpet   Thank you. What we want is that $f^{-1}(U)\to f^{-1}(0)$ is a deformation retraction but not only a retraction.

@LelongWang Oh I see, that's a subtlety I overlooked.

@red-trumpet   I use the term "tubular neighborhood" of a fiber $f^{-1}(0)$ to denote $f^{-1}(V)$ for some open neighborhood $V$ of $0$.

@LelongWang Okay, I think my solution works anyway, because sub-complexes are neighborhood deformation retracts.

@red-trumpet  Sorry for the delayed response.

In Wikipedia, "the inclusion of a subcomplex in a CW complex is a cofibration." However, I am unsure whether a complex space or complex manifold qualifies as a CW complex.
If the retract in Łojasiewicz's triangulation theorem can be replaced by a deformation retract, then another question arises: why does $f^{-1}(U)$ also deformation retract to $f^{-1}(0)$ ? (For a retract, this is straightforward to verify, but it seems that for a deformation retract, it is not as easy to establish.)

